# GTK4 progress bar is not updating

Tags: c, progress-bar, gtk4

have problem with GTK4 app written in C - progress bar value is not updated.

In apps window for first I show some data loaded from xml. After confirmation this screen I hide vBox with data and create
new one with progress bar which I want actualize according progres. But progressBar is shown with value 0. Zero is shown for whole time
of another counting and than app goes to its third screen (without progressbar reached 100% value).

When I want update progress bar I emmit my custom signal "custom-signal-update-progress". I can see that app is in callback function
(from comandline output). I can also see that percentage value sended to progressbar is also increased.

This behaviour is in win10 but also in xubuntu 21.10.

Please could anybody give me any advice how to solve it?

part of code:

```
static void
update_progress (gpointer data) {
    printf("update_progress value %f  index %d \n",progressValue, checkedTestPlace);
    gpointer bar = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "bar");
    gpointer window = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "window");

    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(bar),progressValue);

    if (progressValue >= 1.0) {
        g_signal_emit_by_name(window, "custom-signal-hide-progress");
    };
}

static gboolean
start_test_pcace_checking (gpointer data) {
    gpointer window = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "window");

    unsigned int vectSize = testPlaceVector.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectSize; ++i) {
        progressValue = (gfloat) (i+1) / (gfloat) vectSize;
        printf("we are sending signal for update \n");
        g_signal_emit_by_name(window, "custom-signal-update-progress");
        if (testPlaceVector.at(i).defaultValue.compare("YES")==0) {
            //check_test_place (testPlaceVector.at(i).address, testPlaceVector.at(i).name);
        }
        sleep( 1 );
    }
    return false;
}

static void
close_chooser_window (gpointer data) {
    cout << "test places changes:"<<endl;
    vypis_vektor(testPlaceVector);

    gpointer window = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "window");
    gpointer box = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "box");
    gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(box));

   GtkWidget *vBox;
   GtkWidget *bar;
   GtkWidget *lab;

    vBox =  gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,3);
    gtk_box_set_homogeneous (GTK_BOX (vBox), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), vBox);

    lab =  gtk_label_new ("checking proggress");
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vBox), lab);

    bar = gtk_progress_bar_new ();
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(bar),0.0);
    gtk_progress_bar_set_show_text (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(bar), TRUE);
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vBox), bar);

    lab =  gtk_label_new ("");
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vBox), lab);

    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "window",window);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "box",vBox);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "bar",bar);

   g_timeout_add(200,start_test_pcace_checking,window);
}

static void
app_activate (GApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *win;
    GtkWidget *vBox;
    GtkWidget *btn;
    GtkWidget *chBtn;

    win = gtk_application_window_new (GTK_APPLICATION (app));
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "Git Status - choose what check");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (win), 400, 300);

    testPlaceVector = load_config_xml();

    vBox =  gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,3);
    gtk_box_set_homogeneous (GTK_BOX (vBox), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (win), vBox);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testPlaceVector.size(); ++i)
    {
        chBtn = gtk_check_button_new_with_label (testPlaceVector.at(i).name.c_str());
        if ( testPlaceVector.at(i).defaultValue.compare("YES") ==0) {
            gtk_check_button_set_active(GTK_CHECK_BUTTON(chBtn),true);
        }
        gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vBox), chBtn);
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(chBtn),"toggled",G_CALLBACK(check_button_clicked),chBtn);
    }

    btn = gtk_button_new_from_icon_name("emblem-default");
    //gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(btn),"OK");
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (vBox), btn);

    //tu si nadefinujeme nas signal - kterej poslem, kdyz dozkoumame jeden testovaci stav a budem potrebovat aktualizovat progress bar
    g_signal_new("custom-signal-update-progress", G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, 0, NULL, NULL, g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER, G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);
    //tu priradime obsluznou proceduru k nasemu signalu
    g_signal_connect(win, "custom-signal-update-progress", G_CALLBACK(update_progress), NULL);

    g_signal_new("custom-signal-hide-progress", G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, 0, NULL, NULL, g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER, G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);
    g_signal_connect(win, "custom-signal-hide-progress", G_CALLBACK(hide_progress), win);

    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(btn), "window",win);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(btn), "box",vBox);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(close_chooser_window), btn);

    gtk_widget_show (win);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkApplication *app;
  int stat;

  //app = gtk_application_new ("git.status.checker.gui", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  app = gtk_application_new ("Git.status.icon", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (app_activate), NULL);
  stat =g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);
  return stat;
}
```

comandline output:

```
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,111111  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,222222  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,333333  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,444444  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,555556  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,666667  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,777778  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 0,888889  index 0
we are sending signal for update
update_progress value 1,000000  index 0

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 18.095 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: I have also tried define GtkWidget *bar as a global variable, but with same result - progress barr is not moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have post this question also in gnome.org - and with these guys - We found the solution.
If anyone interest in it:
https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gtk4-progress-bar-is-not-updating/9317/3

Comment: Hello there, 
I have the same issue, I tried to look into the solution proposed on the gnome discourse thread however, there is no piece of code provide, only that you could use `g_idle_add` (and I cannot understand the rest) ... I am sorry but no matter what I tried with that it does not work, I guess I do not have the knowledge to understand how to code a solution :-(

And no way to find an example so far ...
Would you mind sharing a example piece of code to help ?

Regards.

S.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71365107/22768315  shows a working example of a progress bar.